# About mvc:intercepter,how to set excluded path

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

As we know, we can config an interceptor like that:

```
 <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/outfit/**" />
        <bean class="OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
            <property name="sessionFactory">
                <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
            </property>
        </bean>
```

My question, how to configure excluded path?

Comment: please use comments rather than editing my answer. As for your question - make such a property on your custom intercepetor (one that extends the OSIV interceptor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can declaratively. But within the interceptor you can add an `if(..)` and verify whether the request uri should be excluded. You can set the exclusion paths as a list property in the interceptor xml definition.

For that you will have to extend the OSIV interceptor and add that custom logic & exclusion list property.

Comment: very sorry for that! I'm fresher

Comment: sorry for appending my content to your answer.extend the OSIV is appropriate.thanks! meantime,I find out other way.Add more than one  mapping path to specify interceptor as following   <mvc:interceptor>
   <mvc:mapping path="/outfit/**" />
   <mvc:mapping path="/user/**" />
   <mvc:mapping path="/test/**" />
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
     <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
   </bean>
  </mvc:interceptor>

Answer (score 10):

Since Spring 3.2 they added that feature.

See this example from the Spring documentation:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
<mvc:interceptor>
    <mapping path="/**"/>
    <exclude-mapping path="/admin/**"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptor>
<mvc:interceptor>
    <mapping path="/secure/*"/>
    <bean class="org.example.SecurityInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptor>
```

Here's the [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors) to the doc

Comment: how to do it in Spring 4 ?? I'm getting this error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'mapping'. One of '{"http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref, "http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/mvc":interceptor}' is expected

Comment: @ChrisSim you have to had the prefix `mvc:` to `mapping` and `exclude-mapping` tags.