# How to Set “exclude-mapping” in Spring MVC Interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Here is my XML configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

     ...

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

        ... ">

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <resources mapping="/style/**" location="/resources/style/" />
    <resources mapping="/script/**" location="/resources/script/" />
    <resources mapping="/images/**" location="/resources/images/" />
    <resources mapping="/uploaded/**" location="/resources/uploaded/" />

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor>
            <mapping path="/**" />

            <exclude-mapping path="/style/**" />
            <exclude-mapping path="/script/**" />
            <exclude-mapping path="/images/**" />
            <exclude-mapping path="/uploaded/**" />
            <exclude-mapping path="/resources/**" />

            <beans:bean class="com.example.MyInterceptor" />
        </interceptor>
    </interceptors>

</beans:beans>
```

My issue is when I browse a file in `/style` or other path in exclude mappins, such as `/style/style.css`, the interceptor code still run. Even if I change the config to `<exclude-mapping path="/style/*" />`, the issue still happen.

How do I set the config file to let `<exclude-mapping>` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

As [what gamerkore said in About mvc:intercepter,how to set excluded path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15955677/1618596) said, spring add this feature in version 3.2 (my project had used ver. 3.1.1.RELEASE). It can work after updating the version of spring (I updated it to ver. 4.2.0.RELEASE)

Comment: So how did you get it working then with the multiple exclude paths? It would be nice to see your code posted in the solution. I have multiple paths to exclude but it is not working for me.